# Получение данных JSON с сайта

Tags: c#, json

Доброго времени суток, у меня есть сайт и в нём небольшое API, как мне в C# получить данные из этого API.

```
{
    "transport": "POST",
    "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
    "contentType": "application\/json",
    "SMDVersion": "2.0",
    "target": "http:\/\/localhost\/server\/json",
        "services": {
        "API.test": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [],
            "returns": "string"
        },
            "API.getData": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [{
                "type": "integer",
                "name": "num",
                "optional": false
            }],
            "returns": "array"
        }
    },
        "methods": {
        "API.test": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [],
            "returns": "string"
        },
            "API.getData": {
            "envelope": "JSON-RPC-2.0",
            "transport": "POST",
            "parameters": [{
                "type": "integer",
                "name": "num",
                "optional": false
            }],
            "returns": "array"
        }
    }
}
```

Например, из API.test. Для java я пользовался JSONRPCClient, а получал данные

```
string = "client.callString("API.test")";
```

Решил эту задачу
кому интересно, вот код

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/server/json");
                request.Method = "POST";
                string postData = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"API.getData\", \"params\":[2],  \"id\": 1}";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // read the response
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: На хабре есть вот это http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/44451/ , я особо не вникал в сокровенные тайны, но насколько я помню, там достаточно просто и никаких библиотек подключать не нужно - все из коробки.

Answer (score 2):

Я для парсинга json ипользую класс `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`